# Reshape array in a mat-file

Tags: matlab, reshape, hdf5

I am trying to modify a mat-file in-place using the hdf5-interface.

I have a simple mat-file containing a 2D array of size [K x L*M], and wish to reshape it into a 3D array of size [K x L x M], without modifying the data or datatype. Normally I would read the data, do a val = reshape(val,[K,L,M]); and write it back to file. But can I accomplish this by simply modifying the Dataset Size/MaxSize attributes?

Here is what I have so far; it seems like it should be working, but in fact is does not:

```
%%
val = rand(4,9);
save('test.mat','val','-v7.3');
h5disp('test.mat');

%%
fid = H5F.open('test.mat','H5F_ACC_RDWR','H5P_DEFAULT');
dset_id = H5D.open(fid,'/val');
space_id = H5D.get_space(dset_id);
H5S.set_extent_simple(space_id,3,fliplr([4,3,3]),fliplr([4,3,3]));
[ndims,h5_dims] = H5S.get_simple_extent_dims(space_id)
H5F.close(fid);
```

The h5disp-command shows that nothing has changed:

```
>> h5disp('test.mat')

Group '/' 
    Dataset 'val' 
        Size:  4x9
        MaxSize:  4x9
        Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F64LE (double)
        ChunkSize:  []
        Filters:  none
        FillValue:  0.000000
        Attributes:
            'MATLAB_class':  'double'
```

Any ideas? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You can't change the number of dimensions of a dataset in an HDF5 file. The only way to do it is to create a new dataset with the dimensions you want.

Comment: @Yossarian Is that really so? I would have thought that the only difference between a 4x9 and a 4x3x3 dataset is the 'Size'/'MaxSize' tags. The data themselves are stored sequentially, aren't they, it is simply a question of changing the interpretation of them. Anyway, that seems like a pretty strange limitation. Would you happen to know why this is so?

Comment: How the data are stored on disk may be completely different to the representation in memory. By default HDF5 uses B-trees to store data, so there's no guarantee that your data is sequential on disk (and if you had data you want to resize, you wouldn't want it to be!). Additionally, while it is possible to resize datasets (but not change their dimensions!), to do so requires the use of chunks, and it appears matlab doesn't use them.

Comment: I don't want to resize the data, only change the interpretation of their organization. But you are saying that in a 4x9 array and a 4x3x3 array, the data may be stored in different ways. It is not just the Size tags that differentiate them?

Comment: The data *may* be stored in different ways. One of the features of HDF5 is that the actual storage of the data is abstracted away from the representation. In addition to the Size tag, each dataset also has a rank, which is set at creation and cannot be changed. 
If you really don't want to create a new dataset, you might consider calculating the equivalent 2D indices and accessing the data with those.

Comment: I guess that is the way to go, then. Just a bit surprised that you can, apparently, change the size of a dataset, but not the rank/dimensions etc. I would have thought it was the other way around.

Comment: Changing the size of a dataset is only possible if you create it with a MaxSize larger than the current Size, and then you can only change it up to MaxSize (unless MaxSize is unlimited, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution using the matlab's function `matfile` that partially read/write a `.mat` file. Here, the variable `A` is reshaped in the `.mat` file without loading it.

```
A = rand(2,3*4);             %some data in A
save('A.mat', 'A','-v7.3');  %save variable A in A.mat
A1 = reshape(A,2,3,4);       %create A1 as a reshape of A for later comparison
clear A                      %clear A

%modification of the variable within the .mat file
matObj = matfile('A.mat','Writable',true); %partial load of A
matObj.A = reshape(matObj.A,2,3,4);        %reshape saved in A2

%comparison
load('A.mat'); %load the in-mat reshaped version of A
A2 = A;          
isequal(A1, A2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution seems to load the variable from the file an pass it to the reshape function. reshape then returns a array which is written back to file. You can see this by making a 10000x10000 array and reshaping this, while keeping an eye on memory usage. Also, while a reshape in memory takes 0.000015 seconds on my computer, reshaping in file takes over 40 seconds. There should not be much difference in time use.